# Typing Behaviour: Cursor goes back about 12 or 17 characters after pressing space

Tags: 14.04, keyboard

I'm having a typing behavior issue; the cursor goes back about 12 or 17 characters after pressing space. It just happened as I was typing this post, and it went back a few characters. Could it be because I'm using google chrome? Though, it also happens when using gedit.

I have not done any troubleshooting yet besides updating chrome.

```
$ uname -r
4.4.0-36-generic
```

Comment: Do you have a mouse touch pad in front of the keyboard? If so, you may be inadvertently touching it.

Comment: ACtually,  I have deactivated tht touchpad as I thougth that was the reason in the first place

Comment: Similar odd behavior happens to me once in a while. It usually disappears after a reboot.